# Exception thrown in visual studio at return 0 while debugging assembly program

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, assembly

I am writing an assembly language code in Masm Visual Studio to incement a variable thrice.

```
// Increment.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" {
    void incr();
}

int main()
{
    incr();    //Breakpoint Here
    return 0;
}
```

My assembly language code is:

```
PUBLIC incr
EXTERN puts:PROC

.data
     var dword 0005

.code
incr PROC
    mov eax, var
    inc eax  //Breakpoint Here
    inc eax  //Breakpoint Here
    inc eax  //Breakpoint Here
incr ENDP

END
```

The program builds successfully and while debugging, also successfully shows the desired values of RAX, but when it returns to increment.cpp, it throws exception at return 0;(Exception Thrown: Increment.exe has triggered a breakpoint). Why does this happen and how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `ret` instruction to your `incr` procedure so that your function returns properly.

```
incr PROC
    mov eax, var
    inc eax
    inc eax
    inc eax

    ret
incr ENDP
```

The exception you're no doubt getting is being thrown by the debugger thats decided you're mixing calling conventions. What is actually happening here is that execution continues into some debugger padding and it then checks to see why the stack pointer is out of whack - but it should never reach here anyway. You stop it reaching here by returning (via `ret`) from your MASM procedure.

Comment: Thanks:) It really solved the problem in a straight go!

Comment: @Nisha The MSCC may pad space between procedures and modules with `0xCC` bytes, which are opcode of `int3` instruction (which is used for SW breakpoints in debuggers, or as in this case, as a canary of some code running wild into memory area where there is no more code).